# EXCEL 365 - Use wildcard with the lookup_array part of the INDEX MATCH function

Tags: arrays, excel-formula, wildcard, lookup, index-match

I am attempting to use excel INDEX MATCH with the MATCH lookup_array (refdata!$A$2:refdata!$A$150) containing a string e.g. 'AMAZON' which might be part of the MATCH lookup_value ($C2), which is a longer string e.g.''AMZNMKTPLACE AMAZON.CO AMAZON.CO.UK GBR'.

=INDEX(refdata!$A$2:refdata!$C$150,MATCH($C2,refdata!$A$2:refdata!$A$150,0),3)

Is it possible to have the MATCH lookup_array string values set to use wildcards and produce '*AMAZON*' from 'AMAZON' and have this then successfully compared to (or found in?) the MATCH lookup_value which would be ''AMZNMKTPLACE AMAZON.CO AMAZON.CO.UK GBR'?

Comment: `AMZN` does not equal `AMAZON` and therefore it will not match on it even with wild cards.

Comment: yes, but within the string ''AMZNMKTPLACE AMAZON.CO AMAZON.CO.UK GBR', there is the substring AMAZON (twice in fact), i was hoping to get a wildcard match on that

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your structure, but this might work:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(refdata!$A$2:refdata!$C$150,ISNUMBER(FIND(refdata!$A$2:refdata!$A$150,$C2))),,3)
```

It is looking for AMAZON inside of all strings in Column A and then filtering on it. It will spill if there are multiple matches, so if you don't want that, you can do:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(refdata!$A$2:refdata!$C$150,ISNUMBER(FIND(refdata!$A$2:refdata!$A$150,C2))),1,3)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the reply and my apologies for not replying sooner.  I do have a question with regards to the above, the FILTER function will return 'AMAZON', however when the INDEX function is added, the output of the FILTER function is 'AMAZON' rather than a range of cells, have i missed something?

Comment: Hi @keoghb - I realized after I posted this that I should have put something other than just AMAZON in column C. e.g.., **AWS DE AMAZON WEB SERVICES GmbH** and **AMAZON Fulfillment.FR**.  Then the example would be more logical. In any case, this is reversing the search. It does a FIND/SEARCH for Col A in Col C which produces an array of hits. Then multiplies the hit positions by the ROW position using SEQUENCE and FILTERs out the non-hits. I am not sure if that was your goal though.